# javascript enabling input boxes

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I got a form that looks like this:

```
<form method="POST" name="emails" action="../emailing.php">
<select size="1" id="email_template" name="email_template_id">
<option value="1">Welcome</option>
<option value="2">Newsletter</option>
<option value="3">Invoice</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" name="email_template" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="saleid" value="318">
<input type="hidden" name="usertype" value="admin">
<input type="image" name="emails" id="imageField" src="/images/submit.gif" class="send">
</form>
```

On that page where that dropdown shows up i need another input boxes to show up but ONLY when the Invoice option is selected.

Like an Input field (or 2) and maybe a text area for some random text to be entered.

These extra fields should also be sent with the form.

Comment: I think this can be helpful. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689184/select-options-jquery-case-and-show-hide-form-fields][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689184/select-options-jquery-case-and-show-hide-form-fields

Comment: So, are you soliciting bids from developers to work for you, or was there a question in there somewhere? You may want to explain your own attempts thus far, and what went wrong.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP seems to have made, shown or described, *no effort whatsoever* at solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, just grab the change event of your drop down like this:

```
<select size="1" id="email_template" name="email_template_id" onchange="ddlEmail_Change(this)">
...
```

Then on your javascript, you have something like this:

```
function ddlEmail_Change(source){
   var selValue = source[source.selectedIndex].value;

   document.getElementById('extra-fields').style.display = (selValue =="3" ? 'block' : 'none');
}
```

And the extra-fields, actually is a div that you add bellow your drop down like this:

```
<div id="extra-fields" style="display:none">
   <!-- extra fields goes here, this shows up when option 3 is selected -->
</div>
```

I've not tested this but it should work!

Comment: @misulicus hum yes right, sorry was a typo :), I was looking at the HTML.