# Select options: jQuery, Case and show/hide form fields doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't know why this wont work. I did everything like in this same treat [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689184/select-options-jquery-case-and-show-hide-form-fields) I would like to show show one of following div when option in select is selected. When I select some option all divs dissapears but but nothig shows.

Here is my code:

```
<label class="label">
    <span>Typ:</span>
    <select id="type" class="form-control">
        <option value="1" selected="selected">Fotoroleta</option>
        <option value="2">Fototapeta</option>
        <option value="3">Obraz</option>
        <option value="4">Plakat</option>
    </select>
</label>


<div id="select_fotoroleta" class="field" >
 // some code
</div>

<div id="select_fototapeta" class="field" >
 // some code
</div>

<div id="select_obraz" class="field" >
 // some code
</div>

<div id="select_plakat" class="field" >
 // some code
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#type').change(function(){
            var selection = $('#type').val();
            $('.field').hide();
            switch(selection){
                case 0:
                    $('#select_fotoroleta').show();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    $('#select_fototapeta').show();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $('#select_obraz').show();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $('#select_plakat').show();
                    break;
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: `selection` is a string, not a number, you're comparing apples and oranges

Comment: `var selection = parseInt( $('#type').val(), 10)`

Comment: or the shortcut conversion to a number `var selection = ~~$('#type').val()` (there is no danger of range problems or octal values with the data shown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your selection to a number. It is currently a string:

```
var selection = ~~$('#type').val();
```

`~~` is a handly shortcut (instead of the slower `parseInt`). It is fine if you know the numbers are within the range of an int and not in octal format (yours are pure simple decimal values)

**A much better option is to data-drive the selections:**

Then you do not need a `switch` at all and it is quite easy to maintain for loads of links.

e.g. your HTML could have something to match on in the target elements:

```
<div id="select_fotoroleta" data-id="1" class="field">select_fotoroleta</div>
<div id="select_fototapeta" data-id="2" class="field">select_fototapeta</div>
<div id="select_obraz" data-id="3" class="field">select_obraz</div>
<div id="select_plakat" data-id="4" class="field">select_plakat</div>
```

then the code become only this:

```
$('#type').change(function () {
    $('.field').hide();
    $('[data-id=' + $(this).val() + ']').show();
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/oa9z14sk/2/

To select the initial filter, trigger an initial `change` event:

```
$('#type').change(function () {
    $('.field').hide();
    $('[data-id=' + $(this).val() + ']').show();
}).trigger('change');
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/oa9z14sk/3/

Another option (if your data suits it) is to use the `ID`s as the `value`s in the `select`:

```
    <option value="select_fotoroleta" selected="selected">Fotoroleta</option>
    <option value="select_fototapeta">Fototapeta</option>
    <option value="select_obraz">Obraz</option>
    <option value="select_plakat">Plakat</optio>
```

Then the extra `data-id`'s are not needed and the code is even simpler:

```
$('#type').change(function () {
    $('.field').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
}).trigger('change');
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/oa9z14sk/4/

**Update**

As you also want to clear inputs inside divs when you change selection, change the code to add a `find('input').val('');` to the `hide()`:

e.g.

```
$('#type').change(function () {
    $('.field').hide().find('input').val('');
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
}).trigger('change');
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/oa9z14sk/6/

Comment: It works. But now I see other problem. When I start page every div is showed. If I set display:none for .field all divs are hided. How to show only one selected div when I run page ?

Comment: `Trigger` an initial `change` event. I will update the example.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: Could you also tell me how to clear all inserted informations? I mean if I type something in input text inside select_fotoroleta and then I select select_obraz then I agin go to select_fotoroleta I still see every inserted informations.

Comment: @Axwell: Happy to help, but you need to show an example of your HTML *inside the DIVs*. Please modify my last JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/oa9z14sk/4/) and I will show you :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oa9z14sk/5/ also you should know that there is a lot of inputs and I would like to clear them all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the case statements like follows

```
case "0":
    break;
```

as it looks like the value of 'selection' is being passed through as a string not an int.

Answer (score 0):

please check the below code

```
<label class="label"> <span>Typ:</span>

    <select id="type" class="form-control">
        <option value="1" selected="selected">Fotoroleta</option>
        <option value="2">Fototapeta</option>
        <option value="3">Obraz</option>
        <option value="4">Plakat</option>
    </select>
</label>
<div id="select_fotoroleta" class="field">// some code</div>
<div id="select_fototapeta" class="field">// some code</div>
<div id="select_obraz" class="field">// some code</div>
<div id="select_plakat" class="field">// some code</div>

<script>

$('#type').change(function () {
    var selection = parseInt($('#type').val());
    $('.field').hide();
    switch (selection) {
        case 1:
            $('#select_fotoroleta').show();
            break;
        case 2:
            $('#select_fototapeta').show();
            break;
        case 3:
            $('#select_obraz').show();
            break;
        case 4:
            $('#select_plakat').show();
            break;
        default:
             $('.field').hide();
            break;

    }

});

</script>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oa9z14sk/